# How to padding button under image without padding left?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I padding button under image like this code.

```
  body: Center(
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Image(
          image: AssetImage('images/123.jpg'),
        ),
        Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: <Widget>[
              new Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                    vertical: 50.0, horizontal: 0),
              ),
              RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                child: Text('abc'),
              ),
              RaisedButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                child: Text('acb'),
              ),
            ])
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

The result show button padding top and left. I want to padding top only. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `EdgeInsets.only` method to add padding to a particular side

```
Padding(
 padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 50)
)
```

Comment: I have to put Padding() on Row() then it's work.